# Problem with printing string multiple times using multiplication

Tags: python-3.x

Here is the code:

```
# Assignment 1

import random 
import os
import sys
import datetime     # for current year

name = input("What is your name? ")
print("Hi", name, end="")                   # end="" -> no new line
sys.stdout.write(".\n")                     # sys.stdout.write to have period right after previous string(no whitespace)

age = int(input("What is your age? "))

now = datetime.datetime.now()               # current date
year_when_hundo = now.year - age + 100
message = ("The year will be " + str(year_when_hundo) + " when you are 100 years-old.")
print(message)

num = int(input("Enter another number. "))  
for x in range(num):                        # prints previous message x times (on separate lines) depending on input given by user
    print(message)
```

The program ends abruptly when I enter the input for the following statment `num = int(input("Enter another number. "))`

I don't see what the issue is, can anyone see the problem?

Comment: I can run it without any problem, is there any error message showing when you run it?

Comment: @olinox14 No I don't get any error message when running the file. I'm using notepad++ as the text editor. To run the file, I type `C:\Python39\python.exe "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"` into the textbox.

Comment: That's hard to determine from there. Only thing coming in my mind is to advise you the use of a "real" IDE, like [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/). I'm on linux and can not test with n++ for the moment...

Comment: I found a solution, adding the -i argument seems to have solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. To run the program, I typed `C:\Python39\python.exe "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"` into the textbox. I use Notepad++ as the text editor. I updated the command to `C:\Python39\python.exe -i "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"` and now it seems to be working correctly.